# Implement FormView in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination, navigation

I want to show my records one at a time with navigation options to move to next/previous records. Is there any automatic option in MVC? I think I am looking for something like `FormView` (from Web Forms) in MVC using which we can show a single record in a form layout with paging options.

This is what I have done so far. Control on the left is a `Panel` with manual navigation buttons to navigate between records and on the right is the child grid that shows child record for each record selected in the left panel.

[image]

Comment: No there is no _automatic option in MVC_. Use ajax to call a server methods that returns the next or previous object (passing a value indicating the current position) and update the DOM in its success callback

Comment: this is what Im already doing . thanks anyways :)